# Cron does not execute xinit command

Tags: x11, cron

I have a command that works perfectly when launched from the prompt:

```
xinit /home/user/myscript.sh -- /usr/bin/Xvfb :1 -screen 0 1x1x8
```

But is not executed when put in crontab:

```
@reboot xinit /home/user/myscript.sh -- /usr/bin/Xvfb :1 -screen 0 1x1x8
```

Content of myscript.sh :

```
#!/bin/sh
dbus-launch
pulseaudio --start
sleep 99999999
```

See output of `htop`, command is weirdly executed:

[image]

Even though the X session is active on reboot.

Comment: Why on Earth are you using `xinit` to have the PulseAudio daemon running?

Comment: Because Pulseaudio needs dbus, and dbus needs X. Without X, Pulseaudio can only run in system mode, which is bad as the official website says : http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/WhatIsWrongWithSystemWide/

Comment: That's not true.  I run pulseaudio as a non-privileged user on a system without X or dbus; it complains (`[pulseaudio] core-util.c: Failed to connect to system bus`) but it runs normally. However, I'm not sure how it well it will work within X if you then start X up.

Comment: If your DBus depends on X, consider changing distribution since it is seriously flawed. The opposite is (unfortunately) true however - latest desktops do depend on DBus. Even for pulseaudio I think the dependency is not hard (i.e. you can run it without DBus connection).

Comment: Well it doesn't work on my system (Raspbian), PA clearly says "Can't run without X session" and it actually doesn't work. With the xvfb trick it works perfectly. Any suggestion ?

Comment: By whatever coincidence, the system I'm referring to is Raspbian too (I sometimes use the pi as a sound server).  I screwed around with the configuration a lot though, I'll have a look and see what the differences are from the stock image. Anyway, I think (part of) the issue might be that when run via cron, you are actually running pulseaudio system wide as root, and it doesn't like to do that.

Comment: *"what the differences are from the stock image"* -> not much.  Besides the stuff to make it work on the network, the only thing I added was an `/etc/pulse/default.pa` with `load-module module-alsa-sink device=hw:0,0 sink_name=bcm1` and `set-default-sink bcm1`.  PA can be a real pain, every time I have to figure something out with it it takes *way* too long.

Comment: What's the problem? `xinit` and `Xvfb` are executed, as is your script. Is there a problem with DBus? with Pulse?

Answer (score -1):

You are missing the information which user your command should run under, better do:

```
@reboot root xinit /home/user/myscript.sh -- /usr/bin/Xvfb :1 -screen 0 1x1x8
```

had a similar problem and put it here: http://www.linuxintro.org/wiki/Scheduling_tasks#crontab

Comment: That depends. If it is in a user-specific crontab file, then you don't need and absolutely do not want the username field. If it's in a system crontab file, then you do need to specify the username. The question doesn't seem to say which.

Comment: thanks, I did not know user-specific crontab files exist. kursus, are you talking about /etc/crontab?

Comment: The command is executed by user `pi`, so that line is obviously in `pi`'s crontab, not in a system crontab. Even without this clue, if the line was in a system crontab, cron would complain that the user `xinit` doesn't exist and it wouldn't execute anything.